# gem-ctags won't generate any tag

Tags: ruby, vim, rubygems

There's a problem when I use `gem install gem-ctags`
and then `gem ctags`, It doesn't show any message and doesn't generate any tags on the terminal, nor is there any gem's tags in my tag file.

[image: Image about gem ctags problem]

This link is my dotfile, https://github.com/HexterCH/dotfile, is there anything I do wrong? Let me know if information is not enough.

Comment: Could you try to remove gem plugin from your zshrc and `gem ctags` again?

Comment: Hi @larrylv, thank you for your advise. It's work. I think gem plugin form mine zshrc has conflict with gem-ctags. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution from @larrylv, and it's work.

Remove gem plugin for zshrc, it will make conflict in your gem path.
after that, source zshrc file and run gem ctags again.

You can chase your gem path by using `gem env home`.
It should be like `/Users/<your name>/<your ruby manager>/versions/<your ruby version>/lib/ruby/gems/`